# Totals over rolling timeframe

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series

I have my data arranged like this:

```
obj_id    quantity date
1         3        2014-05-06
2         2        2014-03-12
3         5        2014-10-07
4         7        2014-05-09
2         8        2014-12-31
1         5        2014-01-16
4         1        2014-07-26
3         2        2014-09-15
...
```

What I need is to find the OBJ_ID's that have the SUM(quantity) > MAX over the period of RANGE days.
In my case MAX is 18 and RANGE is 31 days.

In other words, every given OBJ_ID recieves QUANTITY (no matter of what) from time to time. I need to find OBJ_IDs that had received in total more than 18 and dates that this OBJ_ID recieved Qs span over less than 31 days. Doh.)

I think I need to use LAG here, but not sure how the whole thing should be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want where the date is within the last 31 days?

Comment: @tbone nope, any 31 days - thats why it's "rolling". not sure if my wording is correct tho.

Answer (score 1):

This might need some tweaking as I didn't have the time to decently test it, but maybe it'll get you on the right track:
(I've assumed you want the records where the date is within the last 31 days)

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM tblTable
WHERE date between DATEADD(day, -RANGE, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
HAVING SUM(quantity) > MAX
GROUP BY obj_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but the records I'm interested in could fall into any consec. 31 days. Sorry if I wasn't clear enogh

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently testing a solution a colleague of mine has quickly put together:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
            SELECT A.obj_id
            , A.date
            , A.in_month_date
            , A.date - A.in_month_date AS in_month
            , A.quantity
            , A.in_month_quantity

            FROM (
                            SELECT A.obj_id
                            , A.date

                            , FIRST_VALUE(A.date)
                            OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY A.obj_id
                                            ORDER BY A.date
                                            RANGE BETWEEN 31 PRECEDING
                                            AND CURRENT ROW
                            ) AS in_month_date

                            , A.quantity

                            , SUM(A.quantity)
                            OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY A.obj_id
                                            ORDER BY A.date
                                            RANGE BETWEEN 31 PRECEDING
                                            AND CURRENT ROW
                            ) AS in_month_quantity

                            FROM mytable A
            ) A
) A
WHERE A.in_month <=  31
AND A.in_month_quantity >  18
```